# Autofac.Integration.WebApi - Create Singleton

Tags: asp.net-web-api, autofac, ioc-container

Folks,

from what I understood, the Autofac.Integration.WebApi helps creating instances in a WebAPI project.

I have a couple classes registered in my global.asax:

```
    builder.RegisterType<ExecutionContextResolver>().As<IExecutionContextResolver>().InstancePerRequest();
    builder.RegisterType<LoggingService>().As<ILoggingService>().InstancePerRequest();
```

Instances of these are created automatically via constructor injection within my controller constructor. My best guess is, that these instances are per request lifetime. So far, so good.

But imagine, I have a "relatively" long running service call. Within this call a good bunch of components will try to access the same instances of a class (ConfigurationService, e.g.).

Two options are:

- make the instance accessible via interface and carry it along all components
- get the single instance from a container

I want to keep my components decoupled, so I decided to use the Autofac container for getting a singleton within each component.

But if I register my type as

```
builder.RegisterType<ConfigurationService>().As<IConfigurationService>().SingleInstance();
```

I'll get the following error:

> No scope with a Tag matching 'AutofacWebRequest' is visible from the
>   scope in which the instance was requested. This generally indicates
>   that a component registered as per-HTTP request is being requested by
>   a SingleInstance() component (or a similar scenario.)

Is there any way to handle singletons within Autofac.Integration.WebApi?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you share your `ConfigurationService` ctor ? does it rely on a service that depends on a per-HTTP request ?

Comment: It actually does. It relies on a services that is a context for each request. Do you think that is the issue?

Comment: When *Autofac* will create the singleton, it won't have any per-http scope available. this is why you have this error message

Comment: "Do you think that is the issue?" - this is exactly what the error message is telling you if you really read it.

Answer (score 0):

As the error message indicates, your ConfirugationService singleton has some dependencies that are registered with "per request" lifetime scope. This breaks the dependency tree since your singleton component gets instantiated when no request scope is available and even worse, if per chance you get it working (there will be a request scope available at the time the singleton is instantiated for the first time), after the request is done, all "per request" components will be disposed and your singleton will crash on any usage of those components.

Comment: Thanks Alexey. That all makes sense to me and helped a lot to understand the behavior of the system! Please bare with me, as I'm relatively new to Autofac and web requests. With a little bit of experience, the error message might have been more helpful to me.